# How to disconsider NAs in a equation?

Tags: r, na, dplyr

I have the following code:

```
testset2 <- testset %>%
  left_join(movie_dev, by="movieId") %>%
  left_join(user_dev, by="userId") %>%
  mutate(prediction = naive + ifelse(is.na(testset$movieid_dev),0,testset$movieid_dev)  +ifelse(is.na(testset$userid_dev),0,testset$userid_dev))
```

When I explore the df, most of the prediction column is working perfectly.
But it will work only for cases (movieid and userid) already known by the training_set.
For all other unknown cases, prediction variable should only consider the naive object (a constant) and insert zero for unknown movieid and userids. 
But instead, I'm getting NAs.
What should I do?

Comment: Hi Valdir, welcome to SO, could you please provide a reprex, look into dput

Comment: The `tidyverse` package has a `replace_na` function that you can replace na with zero.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno! I have already tried replace_na but unsuccessfully. At last, I tried the following: testset$movieid_dev[is.na(testset$movieid_dev)] <- 0 and it worked!